# Pass the text to be displayed on button as a paramter

Tags: html, angular, button

I written a html code which calls, an uploader component.
`<app-uploader [Details]="Details" (onSubmit)="onSubmitEvent($event)"> </app-uploader>` 
Now the app-uploader component has a line something like:

```
<button mat-button
          [disabled]="(canSubmit$ | async) === false"
          color="primary"
          i18n="button text, submit file for uploading"
          (click)="submitUpload()">
    Submit
 </button>
```

However, I don't want the text Submit to appear for my particular use-case.The app-uploader component is a global component and hence I could not change the text directly there. Is there any way to pass any argument when I call the component from my html file such that the word Submit gets overridden while deploying my project?

Comment: Is `app-uploader` a component written by you or you are importing and using the component out of the box?

Comment: It's not written by me, but by my other team members, but I can access and make changes into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment and the post, to me it seems that this button should be showing a different text depending on the use case.

I suggest to define an input field in the `UploaderComponent` and then display that as the text of the button.

`uploader.component.ts`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploader',
  templateUrl: './uploader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploader.component.scss']
})
export class UploaderComponent {
  @Input() buttonText: string = 'Submit';  // default value is submit
  // ...

  constructor() {}

  // ...
}
```

`uploader.component.html`:

```html
<button mat-button
          [disabled]="(canSubmit$ | async) === false"
          color="primary"
          i18n="button text, submit file for uploading"
          (click)="submitUpload()">
    {{buttonText}}
 </button>
```

Now you use the component as follows (`[buttonText]="Your favorite text"`):

```html
<app-uploader [buttonText]="Your favorite text" [Details]="Details" (onSubmit)="onSubmitEvent($event)"> </app-uploader>
```